# Probabilty using indicator

Tags: probability

> Suppose that there are $K$ types of butterflies in a forest. A scientist goes to the forest and captures $n$ butterflies. Suppose that each type of butterfly is independently captured with probability $\frac1k$, and let $X=\{1,2,3,\dots,K\}$ be the number of distinct types of butterflies captured. For example, if $K = 3$, $n = 5$ and the caught butterfly types are AABAB then $X = 2$. Calculate $\operatorname E(X)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)$.

How can I set up the indicator variable?

I have tried: Let $I=1$, then if the $i$th type of butterfly was caught, since $X = I_1+\dots+I_n$ $E(X) =\frac nk$. Is that right?

Comment: See coupon collector's problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: Hint: Type $k$ is not drawn with probability $$\left(1-\frac1k\right)^n$$ Types $k$ and $\ell\ne k$ are not drawn with probability $$\left(1-\frac2k\right)^n$$ These imply the expectation and variance of $X$, do you see why?

Comment: Yeah I understand the coupon collector's problem but I still don't know how to solve this one. For coupon's problem I just set Xi = # of trails to make the type increase from i to i+1, then I add them up I can get the answer.

Comment: I think I know how to calculate the E(X) now...

Comment: Hi when I calculate the Cov(Xi,Xj), I cannot treat E(XiXj) = 1-(1-2/k)^n, right? Because 1-(1-2/k)^n means that at least one of type i and type j is caught